# To remove all div from data extracted by web scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I wanted to remove all `div` from data before storing it in excel data.
for example:

```
seven_days= soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'price'})
name= seven_days.text.strip()
```

It can remove only one `div`, I want something like this

```
seven_days= soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'price'})
```

But I can't remove `div` start and end tag.

Comment: What do you mean by *remove*? Do you want to extract it, or delete it?

Comment: @sonia kindly upvote or accept the answer to help the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by *remove* you mean you want to extract it, you can use this (I'm guessing that you want all the texts in a list named `name`):

```
name = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'price'})]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, your requirement is not very clear to me.
But I think you can use `findAll()`

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


raw_text = "text_with_div_tags"
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_text)
seven_days = [] # For debugging only
names = []
for div_tag in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'price'}):
    seven_days.append(div_tag)  # For debugging only
    names.append(div_tag.text.strip())

#  names list has text information without div tags.
for name in names:
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **code**:

```
seven_days= [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'price'})]
print(seven_days)
```